# Powers when working with primitive polynomials

Tags: modular-arithmetic

When we work with polynomials modulo $m(x)$ where m(x) is a primitive polynomial over $GP(p^{m})$, i know that i can take every coefficient of any polynomial and replace it with it's congruent modulo $p$. (i don't know what's the point in doing this,i think it's a definition).

Moreover, is this also valid for exponents? And why ?

For example, we have $p(X) = x^{3}+x+1$ over $GP(2^{3})$ and a is the primive element. Then why $a^{8} \equiv a$ ?

Comment: Are you asking if for example $x^{p+a}\equiv x^a$?

Comment: Added more in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *evaluating* polynomials over a finite field of size $q$ at a point $b\ne0$, you can replace $b^{q-1}$ by $1$, by Lagrange's theorem applied to the multiplicative group of the field. In other words, you can reduce exponents mod $q-1$.

For instance, $a^{8} = a$ because $a^{7} = 1$ in $GP(2^{3})$.

The point is: $x^8-x$ is the zero *function* but *not* the zero *polynomial*.